# Define decimal separator with vroom

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse, vroom

I often face csv files, which were saved with a German locale and are therefore not properly comma-separated, but rather are separated with a semi-colon. This is of course easily solvable by defining the separator. But `vroom` in contrast to for example `fread` does not offer the possibility to also define the decimal separator.
Therefore, numerical values with a `,` as decimal separator are imported as characters or wrongly without any decimal separator and thus really large numbers.
Is there a way to directly define the decimal separator similar to the way it works in `fread`?

```
library(vroom)
library(data.table)
   
df <- data.table(row.num = 1:10
                 , V1 = rnorm(10,10,5)
                 , V2 = rnorm(10,100,30))

fwrite(df, file = "vroom_test.csv", sep = ";", dec = ",")

fread(input = "vroom_test.csv", sep = ";", dec = ",")

vroom(file = "vroom_test.csv", delim = ";")
# definition of custom locale does allow that
vroom(file = "vroom_test.csv", delim = ";", locale = locale(grouping_mark = ".", decimal_mark = ",", encoding = "UTF-8"))
```

Comment: I searched the `?vroom` help page for "decimal" and found the `locale` argument, which says *"you can use `locale()` to create your own locale that controls things like the default time zone, encoding, decimal mark, big mark, and day/month names."* Have you tried that?

Comment: Ok, added the solution, not sure if `grouping_mark` and `decimal_mark` need to be defined both, but better safe than sorry. Thanks

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer, not edit it into your question! [Answering your own question is strongly encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: As for whether grouping_mark and decimal_mark both need to be included, it will depend on your input file whether both are present. As you say, better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the solution is rather straight-forward and the only thing necessary is to include the `locale()` option to the `vroom` call.
Possible options to the `locale` option can be found in its documentation.

```
vroom(file = "vroom_test.csv", delim = ";", locale = locale(grouping_mark = ".", decimal_mark = ",", encoding = "UTF-8"))
```